# Averaging values of same keys in nested hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a nested hash that looks something like this:

```
    main_hash = [[
  {"a"=>{:x=>70.1}, "b"=>{:x=>97.17}, "c"=>{:x=>97.25}}], 
  [{"a"=>{:x=>70.05}, "b"=>{:x=>97.17}, "c"=>{:x=>97.25}}], 
  [{"a"=>{:x=>70.12}, "b"=>{:x=>97.17}, "c"=>{:x=>97.25}}], 
  [{"a"=>{:x=>70.08}, "b"=>{:x=>97.17}, "c"=>{:x=>97.23}}]]
```

I want to end up with one hash with same keys a...f and each key has a corresponding average of the values from original hash:

```
return_hash = {"a" => average of all the values[:x] corresponding to "a" in each hash, 
"b" => average of all the values[:x] corresponding to "b" in each hash,
"c" => average of all the values[:x] corresponding to "c" in each hash}
```

I tried to use `merge`and `map`but is there a more efficient block I can use to achieve this result?

SO far I have gone down this route:

```
          keys = []
          values = []
          divider = main_hash.size 
          iteration = main.first.first.size
          iteration.times do
              sum = 0
              keys << main_hash.first[0].first[0]
              main_hash.each do |f|
                f.each do |g|
                  sum += g.dig(cores.keys.first, :x)
                  g.shift
                end
              end
              values << ((sum / divider).round(2))
          ret_hash = keys.zip(values).to_h
```

Comment: Your `main_hash` is actually an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you can do here is just flatten the array to remove the sub arrays and then collect all the values of each hash key into an array.

You then average each array.

```
# loop through the outer array and return a hash
main_hash.flatten.each_with_object({}) do |hash, memo|
  # loop over the keys and values of the hash
  hash.each_pair do |name, value|
    memo[name] ||= []
    memo[name].push(value.dig(:x))
  end
end # {"a"=>[70.1, 70.05, 70.12, 70.08], ... }
  # loop across the values and convert the array to an average
  .transform_values { |ary| ary.sum / ary.length } 
  # {"a"=>70.0875, "b"=>97.17, "c"=>97.245}
```

Or you can use `Hash#merge!`:

```
main_hash.flatten.each_with_object({}) do |hash, memo|
  memo.merge!(hash) do |key, old, new|
   (old.is_a?(Hash) ? old.values_at(:x) : old).push(new[:x])
  end
end.transform_values { |ary| ary.sum / ary.length }
```

Comment: `each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] })` also helps here.

Comment: @tadman - yes, using hash defaults is a good idea. I was just writing it to be as straight forward as possible.

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you so much! I dont have enough reputation to vote your answer. T.T

Comment: You can avoid the `flatten` step by writing the first line as `main_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(hash), memo|`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see what solution you've come up with so far to see if we can improve on it. You could try something like this, using `each_with_object`:

```
# Create a hash to store sum and count of each key
totals = main_hash.each_with_object(Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = { sum: 0.0, count: 0 } }) do |h, acc|
  h.each do |key, value|
    acc[key][:sum] += value[:x]
    acc[key][:count] += 1
  end
end

# Calculate average for each key
return_hash = {}
totals.each do |key, value|
  return_hash[key] = value[:sum] / value[:count]
end

puts return_hash
```

Which would output:

```
{"a"=>70.08749999999999, "b"=>97.17, "c"=>97.245}
```

Comment: I updated the post with what I have come up with so far. I am sure there is a more efficient way of doing this, but I am not well versed in ruby enough to come up with one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I have changed `main_hash` to show that the number of values from which an average is computed need not be the same for all keys (i.e., `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` in the example).

```
main_hash = [
  [{"a"=>{:x=>70.1},  "b"=>{:x=>97.17}, "c"=>{:x=>97.25}}], 
  [{"a"=>{:x=>70.05}, "b"=>{:x=>97.17}, "c"=>{:x=>97.25}}], 
  [{"a"=>{:x=>70.12}, "b"=>{:x=>96.11}, "c"=>{:x=>97.25}}], 
  [{"a"=>{:x=>70.08}, "b"=>{:x=>97.17}}]
]
```

I have also changed `main_hash[2].first[:b][x]` to `96.11` so all the "values for `"b"`" are not the same.

I would compute the averages as follows (somewhat similar to @dlmb's solution though I do not construct arrays).

```
main_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(g),h|
  g.each do |k,f|
    h.update(k=>{ tot: f.values.first, n: 1.0 }) do |_k,o,n|
      o.merge(tot: o[:tot] + n[:tot], n: o[:n] + 1) 
    end
  end
end.transform_values { |g| g[:tot]/g[:n] }
  #=> {"a"=>70.08749999999999, "b"=>96.905, "c"=>97.25}
```

Here the receiver of `transform_values` is found to equal the following.

```
{"a"=>{:tot=>280.34999999999997, :n=>4.0}, "b"=>{:tot=>387.62, :n=>4.0},
 "c"=>{:tot=>291.75, :n=>3.0}}
```